# how to set silent mode for sauce lab pre run - C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I want to use sauce labs `pre-run` capability to run some executable before my tests runs and i would like to set silent mode argument for the `pre-run` capability.
Below is the code snipped what I have been trying so far.

```
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            Dictionary<string, object> obj = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "executable", "http://url.to/my/executable" },
                { "background", true },
                { "timeout", 120 }
            };
            capabilities.SetCapability("prerun", obj);
```

Please suggest how can I set the silent mode here.
I know a [solution in java](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Creating+JSON+Objects+for+Multiple+Pre-Run+Executable+Arguments), But not sure how to do it in C#.

Comment: Did you look right below the Java code on the page you linked? It has code for C#.

Comment: @JeffC - Yeah, I took a look into that as well, It tells how to set the prerun capability for C# but it does not demonstrate how to add arguments for silent mode.

Comment: Let me know if you have any solution for adding silent mode argument.

Comment: You haven't used the C# code on that very page in your example. Did you try it as written? The instructions specifically state not to use a JSON object but you've done that in your example code. Also, if you are using SauceLabs, you can raise a ticket to get an answer directly from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add silent mode args by defining a `LinkedList` and adding the silent mode parameters to it. Finally, add the `LinkedList` object to pre-run arguments with `args` key. Below is the code snippet.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
Dictionary<string, object> prerunParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
prerunParams.Add("executable", "http://url.to/my/executable");
LinkedList<string> args = new LinkedList<string>();
args.AddLast("/S");
args.AddLast("-a");
args.AddLast("-q");
prerunParams.Add("args", args);
prerunParams.Add("background", false);
prerunParams.Add("timeout", 60);
capabilities.SetCapability("prerun", prerunParams);
```